# Одновременное пролистывание нескольких слайдеров Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, swiper

На странице имеется несколько слайдеров (их количество может быть разное). Как сделать так, чтобы все слайдеры работали как один, например проскролил один и все остальные так же отреагировали?

```
<div class="swiper js-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper js-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper js-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper js-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
const swiper = new Swiper('.js-slider', {
 slidesPerView: 2,
 spaceBetween: 20,
});
</script>
```